# Proof of $k[X]\otimes_k L\simeq L[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I would like to prove that for a field extension $k/L$ we have that

$k[X]\otimes_k L\simeq L[X]$

I am not sure if I missed something in my attempt.

So I start with the short exact sequence

$0\rightarrow k \rightarrow k[x] \rightarrow Kx \rightarrow 0$

By tensoring with L we obtain the exact sequence

$k\otimes _k L \rightarrow k[X]\otimes_k L\rightarrow Kx\otimes_k L\rightarrow 0$

I already know that $k\otimes_k L\simeq L$ and $kx\otimes_k L\simeq Lx$ and we have an exact sequence

$L\rightarrow L[x]\rightarrow Lx \rightarrow 0$

so by the four lemma we obtain our desired result.

Is this proof correct? If not what mistake did I make? Is there any other way to see this result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working too hard. These two constructions have the same universal property: both of them describe the free $L$-algebra on an element $X$.

Comment: thank you very much! I tried doing this via the universal property but I couldnt seem to do it

Comment: @slin0: when $A$ is a $k$-algebra, $A \otimes_k L$ represents on $L$-algebras the functor given by $k$-algebra morphisms out of $A$. When $A = k[x]$, the universal property of $k$-algebra morphisms out of $A$ is that they are the same as elements of the underlying set. So $k[x] \otimes_k L$ and $L[x]$ both represent the underlying set functor on $L$-algebras; that's what I mean when I say that they have the same universal property. The isomorphism then follows by Yoneda. (There are stronger things you can say about the naturality of this isomorphism too.)

Answer (score 0):

You could write explicit isomorphism as well:
$$x^n\otimes\alpha \mapsto \alpha x^n$$ It's a routine check that it's well-defined, and satisfies all the necessary properties.